# Set java.util.Date to beginning of the day

Tags: java

I want to reset java.util.Date to the beginning of the day
using

```
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    date = cal.getTime();
```

with

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String s=df.format(date);
    try {
        date = df.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
    }
```

Which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

This one's better in terms of clarity and readability, though both gives same output.

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
date = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

With help of Apache Commons `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils` you can also get the desired result like this:

```
DateUtils.truncate(new java.util.Date(), java.util.Calendar.DATE));
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution (manipulation via `Calendar`) is definitly better. The second solution is just a rather ugly workaround using string-manipulation, that will most likely be slower than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can for first approach and you need not set time in Calendar.

```
// Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
// cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```